# How to Separate each Card from simultaneously flipping back together

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I created an events card that rotates when you click/hover the card and rotates back when you click the arrow left icon at the back.  The action is okay but when I click on the next card the previous card is still rotating . I just need to separate the actions on each of the card, since when you click one card the action seems to follow on the other cards. https://jsfiddle.net/89c76wpx/
[image]

This is the html structure of each of the  card, to distinguish each of the card I added an id=card1 id=card2 etc.

```
<div class="card col">
      <input type="checkbox" id="card1" class="more" aria-hidden="true">  
        <div class="content">

           <div class="front" style="background-image: url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/1943696/Tile%20Event%20Pictures/800px_chicago_skylin_N5DSy.jpg')">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2>Chicago Events</h2>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <label for="card1" class="button" aria-hidden="true">
                      Discover
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="back">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="info">
                         <!-- <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> -->
                        <span>Month</span>
                        <div class="icon">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>Event Type</span>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <!-- <i class="fa fa-door-open"></i> -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                       <!--  <span>Event</span> -->
                        <div class="icon">
                           <!--  <i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
                             -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="description">
                        <ul>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Sep</span> Fall Whiskey</a> </li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Oct</span> Halloween Bar Crawl Fri & Sat </a> </li>
                        <li  class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Dec</span> NYE Bar Crawl </a></li>
                        <li  class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Dec</span> NYE Yacht </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Jan</span> Winter Whiskey </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Feb</span> Winter Tequila </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Mar</span> St Patrick's Bar Crawl </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Jun</span> Summer Whiskey </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Jul</span> Summer Tequila </a></li>
                        <li class="btn draw-border"><a href="" target="_blank"> <span>Aug</span> Air Show Yacht Party </a> </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="location">Chicago Events </div>
                    <div class="price">2019-2020</div>
                    <label for="card1" class="button return" aria-hidden="true">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> 

    $(".return").click(function(e){
    $(".card").addClass("myclass");
    });
   $(".return").mouseout(function(e){
    $(".card").removeClass("myclass");
    })
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle if possible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you please edit the  question with Including CSS also...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/89c76wpx/

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference this here:

```
$(".return").mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".card").removeClass("myclass");
})
```

This way you're telling jQuery to find the closest parent with card class and remove myclass from it so this should fix the above error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".return").data('clicked', false);

    $(".return").click(function (e) {
        $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
        ////$(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("myclass", $(this).data('clicked')==true);

        if ($(this).data('clicked') == true) {
            $(this).closest(".card").addClass("myclass");
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".card").removeClass("myclass");
        }
    });

    $(".return").mouseout(function (e) {
        if ($(this).data('clicked') != true) {
            $(this).closest(".card").removeClass("myclass");
        }
    })
});
```

[Sample Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vsm61df8/)

//===========================================//

```
$(".return").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".card").addClass("myclass");
});
```

//Or

```
$(".return").click(function(e){
    $(this).parents(".card").addClass("myclass");
});
```

Comment: So I added this code, but the action is still the same when you click on the second card the first card rotates as well https://jsfiddle.net/89c76wpx/

Comment: @Chrissa : I have checked Jsfiddle above link. 1. I hovered on first card clicked on return arrow. 2. Then I hovered on second card clicked on return arrow. 3. Now I clicked on first card return arrow and mouse out only first card got rotated..

Comment: @Chrissa : Checking with new fiddle please wait for some time...

Comment: @Chrissa : I am unable to find myclass in JsFiddle css, Please add 5px to10px margin for each card. Please check above solution working fine for you.

Comment: it is on the line 16

Comment: In JsFiddle line no please. Line 16: .wrappers for me in jsfiddle. It is been added in CSS block?

Comment: @Chrissa : Please check this link for demo  https://jsfiddle.net/vsm61df8/

Comment: @Chrissa : Input checkbox is causing the issue. Without jQuery also it is working. Need to work around on this, soon we will find some solution...

Comment: @Chrissa : Without any jQuery it is working fine. Animation control is fully handled in CSS and by Checkbox Checked... https://jsfiddle.net/pwbeL7u4/

Comment: yes, but the arrow left Icon isn't rotating back, when you click on it.

Comment: @Chrissa : Working fine for me in Edge https://jsfiddle.net/pwbeL7u4/. Can you please share the step by step process, so that I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I added the jquery which you suggested in this fiddlw https://jsfiddle.net/zo0fr8te/2/. This is what I want to do when you click/hover on any of the card the card rotates, and when you click the arrow left icon at the back of the card the card will rotate back. In this fiddle the actions is correct the only issue is that when you click the card again it won't rotate anymore

Comment: I think the mobile is not working properly because there is no mouseout function for mobile